Recovery of parameters of Bernoulli random variable with a nonlinear relationship
Given a Bernoulli random variable $X$, whose success probability is $p=wq^\tau$, and the failure probability is $q$. It is clear that $wq^\tau + q = 1$. Suppose $\tau$ is given but $w$ is unknown, can we derive a multiplicative Chernoff bound of $w$ after observing $T$ trials, i.e.,
$$
\mathbb{P}(|\hat{w} - w| \geq \delta_3 w) \leq C\exp(f(\delta_3, p, \tau, T)).
$$
I have some thoughts on this. One is to apply the Chernoff's inequality regarding $p$, but I only obtain a quite complicated form of $\delta_3$, which is
\begin{equation*}
\delta_3=\max \left\{1-\frac{1-\delta_1}{\left(1+\delta_2\right)^\tau}, \frac{1+\delta_1}{\left(1-\delta_2\right)^\tau}-1\right\}
\end{equation*}
where $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ are the parameters in multiplicative Chernoff bound of $p$ and $q$, and the inequality looks like
\begin{equation*}
 \mathbb{P}(|\hat{w}_1 - w_1| \geq \delta_3 w_1)  \leq 2 \exp\left( -\frac{\delta_1^2 T p}{3}\right)+2\exp\left( -\frac{\delta_2^2 T (1-p)}{3}\right)
\end{equation*}
I want to simplify the RHS to make it only depend on $\delta_3$, but fail. I try to bound $\delta_3$ by $2\delta_1$, but the induced relationship between $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ is complex.


As you substituted everything to Chernoff bound, than may you write $f$ in an expicit form? 2) It's better to write which type of inequality you are trying to prove. Do you want R.H.S. depend only on $T$, may in depend on smth.else, e.g., $\tau$? 3) We may put $1$ in R.H.S. Do you want exponintial inequality in variable $T$?


Thanks for the feedback, and I have revised my question. I believe that $f(\tau, T)$ will depend on $\tau$, and hope it looks like a decreasing function in $T$.

Let $\tau=1$ for example. You have a fundamental problem when $q$ is close to $0$ because then $w$ is enormous. Suppose for example $T$ is large and $q=1/T^2$ or $q=1/T^3$. Then $w\approx T^2$ or $w\approx T^3$. But $T$ trials is not enough to distinguish between those two cases (because with probability very close to $1$ you will see all trials successes in both cases). So it will not be possible to approximate $w$ successfully up to a small multiplicative constant. So at the least, your RHS will need some dependence on $w$ (or equivalently $q$ or $p$).

@JamesMartin Thanks for the response, and I believe it is true that we need to include $p$ in the RHS. This is also what I did in the last equation.
